# "Unreachable code detected" error in switch/case statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, enums, switch-statement

I'm getting this error for the following code and it's not possible.

I've checked the program and it runs perfectly, including that method.

Any suggestions on what the source of the unreachable code error is?

```
public static string GetStringNumber(Card a)
{
    switch (a.number)
    {
        case Number.Ace:
            return "Ace";
            break;
        case Number.Two:
            return "Two";
            break;
        case Number.Three:
            return "Three";
            break;
        case Number.Four:
            return "Four";
            break;
        case Number.Five:
            return "Five";
            break;
        case Number.Six:
            return "Six";
            break;
        case Number.Seven:
            return "Seven";
            break;
        case Number.Eight:
            return "Eight";
            break;
        case Number.Ten:
            return "Ten";
            break;
        case Number.Jack:
            return "Jack";
            break;
        case Number.Queen:
            return "Queen";
            break;
        case Number.King:
            return "King";
        default:
            return "Somthing got wrong";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are *returning* from each `case` label, your `break` statements are unreachable.In other words they will never be executed. If you remove the breaks, you won't get the warning.

Comment: Why is he forced to remove the break though?  What if I pass a value of "stack" into that switch statement?  He has lost any kind of console logging or error throw opportunity? How is this beneficial?

Comment: That must be the first time I needed not to put `break;` in a `switch`